# About the solutions of a Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any $n$ such that the equation $n = x^2 + y^2$ ($n, x, y$ belonging to the set of natural numbers) has more of three solutions?

Comment: If you mean ordered solutions, $0 < x < y,$ take $n = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 29 $

Comment: Depends on how you are counting - are $(x,y)=(5,0)$ and $(x,y)=(0,5)$ different answers for $n=25$ The answer, however is use, for "more than $k$" for any $k$. In particular, there are cases where there are more than $3$ solutions.

Comment: @WillJagy Do you really need three primes? I think $5\cdot 13\cdot 17$ is enought.

Comment: @Thomas, could be. I don't remember whether you double with each prime or just add one.

Comment: Definitely, multiply :) @WillJagy

Comment: I think I read that there are $n$ having more than $k$ distinct solutions, for any positive $k$. (This seems clear by multiplication of solutions, but maybe some care to make sure they're all different solutions.)

Comment: Yes, if $p_i\equiv 1\pmod 4$ are distinct primes then $n=p_1p_2\dots p_k$ has $2^{k-1}$ solutions (if you count switching $x,y$ as the same answer.) If $C_n$ is the count for $n$ then if $n,m$ are relatively prime then $C_{nm}=C_{n}C_{m}$ - at least, if $C_n$ allows $x=0$.

Comment: So: $n=5\cdot 13\cdot 17 = 4^2+33^2 = 9^2+32^2 = 12^2+31^2 = 23^2 + 24^2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, yes.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/225972/11619), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/94382/11619) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/167805/11619) for some of the local hits to a suitable search. Degree of relevance varies.

Answer (score 1):

All natural numbers $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$ with primes $p_i\equiv 1(4)$ for all $i$ and $B:=(e_1+1)(e_2+1)\cdots (e_r+1)\ge 8$ have at least $4$ different representations as sum of $2$ squares, in fact $B/2$ different representations, if $B$ is even, or $(B-1)/2$ if $B$ is odd. Of course, there are other $n$ with that property as well. 
So far, this was more or less said already in the comments. However, if you are interested on how to obtain these representations computationally, then you might want to see this discussion here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29644/enumerating-ways-to-decompose-an-integer-into-the-sum-of-two-squares.